# Why are the wrong values being passed when button is clicked

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok, I am trying to get content from a SQL database to populate fields when a button is pushed. The problem is that no matter which button is pushed, it always sends the values of the last row to php. I am a php/mySQL noob. I apologize if this has been asked/answered before, I have been searching the site for hours and not come across anything that has helped me figure it out.

Index page image and Code:[image: index page image]

```
<?php
require_once('database.php');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM omniarticles 
     ORDER BY recid';

$statement1 = $db->prepare($query);
$statement1->execute();
$article = $statement1->fetchAll();
$statement1->closeCursor();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AMS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basic.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Article List</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Publication Date</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        </tr>

        <?php foreach ($article as $articles) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $articles['publicationDate']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $articles['title']; ?></td>
                    <td><form action="view.php" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="recid" 
                                   value="<?php echo $articles['recid'];?>">
                            <input type="submit" value="View">
                        <input type="submit" value="Edit">
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

view.php code:

```
<?php
$recid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'recid');

require_once('database.php');

$q = 'SELECT * FROM omniarticles
    WHERE recid = :recid';
$s = $db->prepare($q);
$s->bindValue(':recid', $recid);
$s->execute();
$title = $s->fetch();
$s->closeCursor();

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AMS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Module5Lab.css">
</head>
<body>
        <label>Article Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="article_title" value="<?php echo $title['recid']; ?>"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label>Article Summary</label>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <label>Article Content</label>
        <textarea rows="20" cols="50"><?php echo $title['content']; ?></textarea>
        <br/>
        <label>Publication Date</label>
        <input type="text" name="publication_date"/>
        <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

The result I am getting is always for the last record, no matter which button I push.
[image]

Comment: i think you should try closing the form tag within the loop

Comment: you need to put more debuging, i need more infos so i can be able to help you.

Comment: do an " echo $recid;" and " print_r($title); so we can see the content of the variables.

Comment: Yep, it was the missing form closing tag. Man, now I feel like a right dunce, I've been staring at this code for hours. Thanks smerny!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly with the line:

$recid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'recid');

I'd recommend doing var_dump($_POST) and seeing what's in the post data.